# Briefing header in Taylor&Francis book template

Tags: header-footer

I can not make header shorter as shown in the pic. I do it in main tex (chapter 5) file but fail. In template directory, there are many files (see attached pic). I dont know  to [image]which file problem is related.  Please help me.

Comment: Hope you didn't get any proper help without provide `MWE`

Comment: there are too many files. thus ı cant provide mwe.

Comment: @DavutKesen, you can always distill a short version from your code, which you can present here ...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can put the Header into a tabular template like so, and add line breaks at appropriate times:

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
  Trapezoidal Fuzzy Multi Aggregation Operator Based on Archimedian Norms and\\ 
  Their Application \\
  ...
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: I'm quite new in latex. So i dont know how to do this. Can you direct me, please?